# Error while pushing the repo to the GitHub using git

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, repository

I am trying to push my project to the GitHub using Git but when I do that I get this error again and again

```
Priya@DESKTOP-I2FML9S MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Client_Site (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 110, done.
Counting objects: 100% (110/110), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (108/108), done.
Writing objects: 100% (110/110), 1.11 MiB | 7.13 MiB/s, done.
Total 110 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/1.1.1t: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have tried to increase teh buffer size, My internet is stable too still I am facing this error.

Comment: Are you connecting through any sort of proxy?

Comment: No i am not using any proxy everything is as usual like normal pc

Answer (score 1):

The message "bad record mac" indicates something is wrong with your connection.

When you make an HTTPS connection, the TLS protocol includes a message authentication code, or MAC, which verifies that the data hasn't been tampered with by an attacker in transit.  (In some cases, an AEAD is used for both encrypting and authenticating the data, but the result is the same.)  That message indicates that that the MAC or AEAD authentication tag is invalid, which means that the data sent by the remote side (in this case, GitHub) is not what you received.  This is always fatal, because it either indicates an intentional attack or a broken connection, and you wouldn't want to receive invalid or tampered data.

All we can tell you here is that there's some sort of problem between your Git version and GitHub, but we don't know where.  It could be a legitimate network problem (your Wi-Fi or network card or router, your ISP, some machine between you and GitHub), or it could be some sort of proxy.  Common kinds of proxies that cause this type of problem are non-default antiviruses or firewalls on Windows (that is, anything not Windows Defender or Windows Firewall), monitoring software, or TLS MITM proxies installed in some corporate environments.  The Git maintainers don't recommend using any such device or software because they are frequently broken in exciting ways.

If you are using an antivirus or firewall other than the default, you should completely uninstall it and reboot, and try again.  If this is a corporate machine and you cannot do that, or you have monitoring software or a TLS MITM proxy, you can try using another machine to push to see if that's related or if it's more likely a network problem.  If it is a proxy, you'd need to contact the maintainer (usually your IT department) and report it broken.

Note that [the Git FAQ explains what `http.postbuffer` really does](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) and why it should never be needed.  It would not have any effect on this problem, since the problem is at the TLS layer, so increasing the buffer size serves only to waste memory.

Comment: currently i am not using any proxy or any kind of firewall or antivirus other then pre installed windows defender, I will try this from my other computer